# Camel testing - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultEndpoint must be specified

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-test

I am trying to create testcases for my camel route using http://camel.apache.org/mock.html . I need to verify the the processors in the route. But the simple test is not working for me.

```
public class CamelRouteTest  extends CamelTestSupport {

  @Override
  public String isMockEndpointsAndSkip() {
    // override this method and return the pattern for which endpoints to mock,
    // and skip sending to the original endpoint.
    return "mock:result";
  }

  @Test
  public void verifyMessageCount() throws Exception {
    template.sendBody("Test");
    getMockEndpoint("mock:result").expectedMessageCount(1);
    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
  }

  @Override
  protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:start").to("mock:result");
        }
    };
  }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultEndpoint must be specified
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:308)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.getMandatoryDefaultEndpoint(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:506)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:370)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `template.sendBody("Test")` try to send `Test` to the default endpoint. As in your code this is not configured it fails.

You could:

- specify which endpoint to use

  ```
  template.sendBody("direct:start", "Test");
  ```
- get an endpoint from the context and set it as the default endpoint

  ```
  Endpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint("direct:start");
  template.setDefaultEndpoint(endpoint);
  template.sendBody("Test");
  ```